# list comprehension for matching pattern

Tags: python-2.7, list-comprehension

Trying an iteration with list comprehension 
list:

```
 >> TOOLS = ['FIREFOX', 'CHROME', 'SAFARI', 'OPERA', 'EI', 'KONQUEROR', 'MOSAIC']
```

list_comprehension:

```
>> [m.group(0) for m in (re.match(r'FIRE', l) for l in TOOLS) if m] 
['FIRE']
```

desired output:

```
 ['FIREFOX']
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of matching, then extracting the match, just use the match itself as the condition.

```
>>> [l for l in TOOLS if re.match(r'FIRE', l)]
['FIREFOX']
```

Comment: @Shah If it worked, please "accept" this answer by clicking the checkmark symbol to the left, to mark the question as being resolved.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
[i for i in TOOLS if not i.find('FIRE')]
```

More intuitive solution:

```
[i for i in TOOLS if i.startswith('FIRE')]
```

Comment: I guess that would work, but you have to admit that `if not find` is _extremely_ couter-intuitive...